# Trying to get a specific column value out of parent row in qtreeview

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtreeview

I have a qtreeview that I populate with hierarchical data like this:

```
- id1                    id1
    -id1.id2             id2
        - id1.id2.id3    id3
```

In my non sample application I want to be able to right click on the last row and select a de-link menu option that then goes and deletes the linking record between id2 and id3. To do this I need the id of the child and the parent.

The problem enters with this bit of code

```
    index = self.eventTree.currentIndex()
    parent_index = index.parent()
    text1 = parent_index.data()
    parent_index = self.model.index(parent_index.row(), 1)
    text2 = parent_index.data()
```

So I grab the current index from the view, get the parent index from the child index. Up to there everything works as I would expect. If I right clicked on the second column on id3 text1 will equal id2.

Since I need to grab a specific column of the parent row I try to adjust the parent index to that specific column by using the model.index function. However when I do it this way I get the top row (id1) instead of id2.

So I am apparently going about this the wrong way, but I'm not sure what else to try right now.

What would be the proper way of adjusting an index to get a specific column out of the index's row?

Here is a working sample of what I am talking about

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from collections import deque

test_data = [
    {"column2": "id1", "column1": "id1", "column3": "id1-value", "lvl": 0},
    {"column2": "id2", "column1": "id1.id2", "column3": "id2-value", "lvl": 1},
    {"column2": "id3", "column1": "id1.id2.id3", "column3": "id3-value", "lvl": 2},
]

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(640, 480)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.eventTree = QtWidgets.QTreeView(self.centralwidget)
        self.eventTree.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 621, 391))
        self.eventTree.setObjectName("eventTree")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 89, 25))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 10, 391, 17))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 640, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Column1", "Column2", "Column3"])
        self.eventTree.header().setDefaultSectionSize(180)
        self.eventTree.setModel(self.model)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.clickHandle)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        self.importData(test_data)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))

    def clickHandle(self):
        index = self.eventTree.currentIndex()
        parent_index = index.parent()
        parent_index = self.model.index(parent_index.row(), 1)
        text = parent_index.data()
        self.label.setText(text)

    def importData(self, data, root=None, extend=False):
        self.model.setRowCount(0)
        if root is None:
            root = self.model.invisibleRootItem()

        seen = {}
        values = deque(data)
        while values:
            value = values.popleft()
            if value['lvl'] == 0:
                parent = root
            else:
                pid = ".".join(value['column1'].split(".")[:-1])
                if pid not in seen:
                    values.append(value)
                    continue
                parent = seen[pid]
            dbid = value['column1']
            parent.appendRow([
                QtGui.QStandardItem(value['column1']),
                QtGui.QStandardItem(value['column2']),
                QtGui.QStandardItem(value['column3']),
            ])
            seen[dbid] = parent.child(parent.rowCount() - 1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is something similar to what I am doing as follows:

```
def __itemSingleClicked(self, index):
    ItemIdxs = self.selectedIndexes()[0]
    Item = ItemIdxs.model().itemFromIndex(index)
    if Item.hasChildren():
        Parnt = ItemIdxs.model().itemFromIndex(index).text()
        self.CntrPane.RefrshTreeSelctd(Parnt)
    else:
        Parnt = ItemIdxs.model().itemFromIndex(index).parent().text()
        Child = ItemIdxs.model().itemFromIndex(index).text()
        self.CntrPane.RefrshTreeSelctd(Parnt, Child)
```

The function RefrshTreeSelctd displays either all the Items that belong to the Parent or it will display only the Items that belong to the Parent's Child

Hope that helps you get going down the right path.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I don't believe this will help though. This still gives me the same column that I clicked just from the parent row. The difficulty I am having is figuring out how to get a specific column from that parent row.

Comment: But if you have a handle to the child row you can get a specific column from it yes? -- and if yes then similarly if you have a handle to the parent row you can get a specific column from it in the same manner -- so using what has been provided you should be able to extrapolate how to pull the specific column you want from the specific row that you want regardless of whether it was the child, parent, grand-parent, great-grand-parent, etc...